# Android : is correct put setOnclickListener or or setOnLongClickListener in onBindViewHolder?

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Can i put setOnclickListener or or setOnLongClickListener in onBindViewHolder?

No problem in this method `onBindViewHolder` to write? **(Is it wise or not?)**

Or better in `ViewHolder` to write?

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {


    myBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //...
        }
    }); }
```

**This method is a bad influence on the speed of the RecyclerView list?**

Comment: I don't think there's anywhere else you could put it...

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. It's just creating and setting a listener. It would be similar overhead to creating and setting a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewHolders are basically caches of your View objects and  inner classe of the RecyclerView.

Since RecyclerView.Adapter is abstract you will have to implement these three methods:

public VH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
public void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position)
public int getItemCount()

you can use an RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener in combination with gesture detection to identify those events.

You can add listeners in your custom adapter implementation. It will be something like:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClicked(int position);
}

public interface OnItemLongClickListener {
    public boolean onItemLongClicked(int position);
}

private Fragment mFragment;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public View v;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        this.v = v;
    }
}

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Fragment fragment) {
    mFragment = fragment;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mFragment.onItemClicked(position);
        }
    });
    holder.v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            mFragment.onItemLongClicked(position);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
. . .
```

}

Comment: This is wrong, you cannot use the position in a callback because it may change and unlike in ListView, you won't get another callback. See documentation for details.

Comment: Reinforcing the comment of yigit, you shouldn't make position final, here is the explanation: youtube.com/watch?v=imsr8NrIAMs&t=34m53s

Answer (score 6):

Add it on your onCreateViewHolder method so that you won't churn listener objects. You should use `vh.getAdapterPosition` to map it back to your data.